# Changing URL SLug of location pages to Parent/Child in ListingPRO

Tags: wordpress, parent-child, permalinks, taxonomy, slug

I am using ListingPro directory theme.
All the location specific pages permalink is like
domain.com/location/city
Even if there is an option to assign Parent to a child ( in my case assign State (Parent) to City), it still doesnt change the URL slug (keeps domain.com/location/city, instead of domain.com/location/state/city )
for example if I create location Dallas, and give parent Texas.
The Dallas page would still be domain.com/location/dallas, not domain.com/location/texas/dallas.
How to achive my goal? (so child would come after parent?). And not mix up anything elsewhere))
Thx. There is a long functions.php file in theme editor. I guess smth should be done there.

seeking solution...........................